# Why is it returning address instead of object?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, memory-address

```
Comparator<Employee> comparator =Comparator.comparing(Employee::getIncome);
Employee minObj= Employee.persons().stream()
                       .min(comparator)
                       .get();
```

This is returning me address instead of an object.

```
toMap.Employee@66133adc
```

What is the problem and how to write it correctly?

Comment: And ... it is NOT the address of the object.  It is the object's *identity hashcode*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably isn't—you have forgotten to override `toString()`.